# Tagging a git repo?

Tags: git

I am new to git (been using svn and mercurial for awhile). Is there a way to 'tag' my git repository? Something like tagging it "version 12, removed red square.". I'd like to pull the source state at the time the tag was added, if I ever need to revert to a known snapshot of the code. Is it possible? Would be cool, if a year from now, I'm looking through my repo and can see all my tags, and pull out the code at different states during development,

Thank you

Comment: [Let me Google that for you.](http://bit.ly/bEIlqj)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is `git tag`, read about it with `git help tag`.

Next time use `git help -a` to find the obvious answer.

Even if you don't have a tag, you can always go through `git log`, find the commit you're interested in, and `git checkout` (or `git tag`) it.